# Run a specific function when an argument is specified using - argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, argparse

Hi Everyone so I have read all of the "similar" posts and have not found a clear answer. What is the most simple way to map an argument to a specific function I have defined?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(" ")

parser.add_argument("-u", "--url")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ip")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--action")
args = parser.parse_args()

def func1(ip):
    do something
func1(ip)

def func2(url):
    do something
func1(url)

def func3(action):
    do something
func1(action)
```

My functions work properly with the arguments, but I do not want say func2 & func3 to run if the -u flag is used, or I only want func3 to run if -a is used. In laymans terms is this possible? The other answers were not clear at all.

Thanks!

Comment: `args.url` will be `None` if that argument is not provided, otherwise a string provided by the user.  Add a `print(args)` statement to your code to get a clearer idea of what the parser does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(" ")
parser.add_argument("-u", "--url")
args = parser.parse_args()

def func1(some_variable):
    print(some_variable)

if args.url:
    func1(args.url)
```

And so on for other args. Hope you get idea.

Comment: Short, simple, and accurate. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a the `args._get_kwargs()` function to see the values and arguments like this

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(" ")

parser.add_argument("-u", "--url")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ip")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--action")
args = parser.parse_args()

arg_dict = dict(args._get_kwargs())

def func1(ip):
    do something

def func2(url):
    do something

def func3(action):
    do something

arg_func_dict = {'ip': func1, 'url': func2, 'action': func3}

for arg, value in arg_dict.items():
    if value != None:
        arg_func_dict[arg](value)
```